# Kalb-Ramond current fall-offs at future null infinity

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, tensor-calculus, asymptotics

I can couple the electromagnetic field to a current generated by the complex scalar field for example:
$S=- \int d^4x \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} + A_\mu J^\mu$
with $J_\mu = i(\partial_\mu \phi^* \phi - \phi^* \partial_\mu \phi)$.

From the large-$r$ falloffs for the scalar field $\phi \in O(r^{-1})$ I can get the large-$r$ falloffs for the current by plugging the asymptotic expansion of the scalar field into the equation for the current.
In this example I get  $J_u \in \mathcal{O}(r^{-2})$ , $J_r \in \mathcal{O}(r^{-4})$ and $J_A \in \mathcal{O}(r^{-2})$ (in retarded Bondi coordinates $(u,r,A,B)$).

If we are looking at the two-form Kalb-Ramond theory with a coupled current

$S = - \int \frac{1}{6} H_{\mu\nu\rho} H^{\mu\nu\rho} + J^{\mu\nu} B_{\mu\nu}$, where $H=dB$ is the 3-form field strenght and $B$ the 2-form gauge field, how can I obtain the fall-offs for the coupled current at large-$r$?
I know it is antisymmetric, $\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}=0$ and the equations of motion are $\partial_\mu H^{\mu\nu\rho} = - J^{\nu\rho}$.
I also know the form of the current

$J^{\mu\nu} = q \int \delta^{(n)} (x-z) dz^\mu \wedge dz^\nu$

([p-form electrodynamics, Henneaux](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01889624))

Now I need to calculate similar fall-off conditions for the different $J$ components like in electrodynamics above (e.g. $J_{uA} \in O(r^{n})$).

How do I do this?

Comment: Is your expression for the current in the second line correct? As far as the question is concerned, could you please be more specific? I do not know exactly how identify the fall-off conditions, but I would suggest to demand the charge associated to $J^{\mu\nu}$ be finite, no?

Comment: I've corrected the expression for the current. But how exactly do I formulate the finiteness of the charge associated to $J^{\mu\nu}$ at future null infinity?

Answer (score 1):

This will not be an answer, as I have some counter-questions regarding your post! However, hopefully it will lead to you answering my counter-questions (presumably in the comments) and me replying back/contributing, clearing, in this way, some things in your mind regarding the behavior of various components' of $J$ in the asymptotic /large $r$ limit!

First of all, you state that you expand the scalar field $\phi(x)$ near the asymptotic regions of space, obtaining, thus, the asymptotic expression for $\phi(x)$! From reading Strominger's "Lectures on the Infrared structure of Gravity and Gauge Theory" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448), I understand that the large $r$ behavior of the field at hand (i.e. the photon field) is determined by requiring that the charge or the energy flux of a Cauchy slice being finite (see discussion above Eq. (2.10.2) in Strominger's lecture notes). To be honest, I do not know which is more fundamental (demanding that some flux be finite or transforming the fields in retarded/advanced Bondi coordinates and expanding around the large $r$ limit). I also do not know if choosing one of the two above-mentioned approaches plays an essential role. My gut tells me that it shouldn't matter, but I still feel that Strominger's demand should not be neglected, so I leave it there for you to think about...

Second, after having a quick look at a paper you cite at a different question (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05634), I can see the exact formula for the three-form field strength components
$$H_{\mu\nu\rho}=\partial_{\mu}B_{\nu\rho}+
\partial_{\rho}B_{\mu\nu}+
\partial_{\nu}B_{\rho\mu}$$
with $B_{\mu\nu}$ being an antisymmetric rank-two tensor gauge field. Hence, following the same approach you seem to describe, the latter should admit an expansion of the form
$$B_{\mu\nu}(x)=e\int\frac{d^3\vec{q}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega_q}
\Big[a_{\mu\nu}(\vec{q})e^{iq\cdot x}+
a_{\mu\nu}^{\dagger}(\vec{q})e^{-iq\cdot x}\Big]$$
where $a_{\mu\nu}^{\dagger}(\vec{q}),\ a_{\mu\nu}(\vec{q})$ are the creation/annihilation operators for the respective field multiplied with some polarization vectors and summed over the potential polarization states (you can find the exact form of the latter operators yourself). The latter field, can be expressed in terms of the Bondi retarded coordinates
$$B_{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{e}{8\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}d\omega_q\omega_q
\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\sin\theta
\Big[a_{\mu\nu}(\vec{q})e^{-i\omega_q u-i\omega_qr(1-\cos\theta)}+
a_{\mu\nu}^{\dagger}(\vec{q})e^{+i\omega_q u+i\omega_qr(1-\cos\theta)}\Big]$$
and the limit of large $r$ can be taken such that
$$B_{\mu\nu}(x)=-\frac{ie}{8\pi^2r}\int_0^{\infty}d\omega_q
\Big[a_{\mu\nu}(\omega_q\vec{x})e^{-i\omega_q u}-
a_{\mu\nu}^{\dagger}(\omega_q\vec{x})e^{+i\omega_q u}\Big]$$
Then, the expression for the various components of the transformed antisymmetric rank-two tensor will be given by general coordinate transformations, as
$$B_{a\beta}(x')=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{'a}}
\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{'\beta}} B_{\mu\nu}(x)$$
where with $x'$ I denote the retarded Bondi coordinates, whereas with $x$ I denote the Minkowski ones (expressed in terms of Bondi coordinates, as we have done above). For instance, it can already be seen (I think and if I am not mistaken) that
$$B_{uu}=B_{tt}=\mathcal{O}(r^{-1})$$
and you can plug in this and the remaining components you find in the expression for the current (from the equations of motion) and determine the current dependence on $r$...

This should give you a valid method for determining the various components of the large $r$ expansion of the $B$ field. Sorry for not being more concrete, but I haven't done the calculation myself. I reply though, in hopes of transferring the way of thinking of other similar calculations (just like some of the ones performed in Strominger's lecture notes) to your case. I hope this helps. If there are any questions, please do not hesitate to leave a comment.

Comment: My aim is it to verify the fall-off conditions of $B$ with the equations of motion of the theory coupled to the current $J$. I write the equations of motion $\nabla_\mu H^{\mu\nu\rho} = J^{\nu\rho}$ in a gauge and then insert the fall-offs for $B$ and $J$. The $J$ fall-offs have to be faster than the expression with the $B$s on the other side. In electrodynamics one could write for example
$J_u^{(-2)} = \partial_u [\gamma^{AB} D_A A_B^{(0)} - A_u^{(-1)}]$ , which is consistent with the fall-offs of $A$. (part1)

Comment: I also think that demanding the charge flux to be finite is probably easier in this case, but I arrive at
$| \int_{S(u)} J^{\mu\nu} d S_{\mu\nu}| = | \int_{S(u)} J^{AB} d S_{AB}| =| \int_{S(u)} J^{AB} \  d\theta_A d\theta_B| <\infty$
where the integration is performed on a sphere $S(u)$ at a fixed retarded time $u$ and for large $r$. This gives me only fall-offs for the angular component $J^{AB} \in \mathcal{O}(r^0)$.  (part2)

Comment: Hi. It seems reasonable to not be able to derive/determine the asymptotic behavior of all the field strength simply by requiring the charge flux to be finite at the asymptotic regions. Afterall, by definition it is defined on a sphere of constant $r$ (s.t. $r\rightarrow\infty$). To specify the $r$ dependence of more components, one can also demand the energy flux to be finite at the asymptotic regions of space (as is done in Strominger's lecture notes!)... This should provide you with further restrictions on the remaining components of $H$ and hence of $J$ through the equations of motion...

Comment: Thank you! So there is nothing wrong with the form of the oriented surface element?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Where did you find the starting expression?? Usually the conserved charge is the temporal component of some current, integrated over a Cauchy slice. Here you are integrating over a Cauchy slice all of the components, which is something I find a bit odd... If you want me to take a better look, could you please point me to the direction you are working (i.e. where did you find the starting expression etc, what are the steps you have taken)??

Comment: In electrodynamics one writes the condition as $| \int_{\mathcal{I}^+} J_\mu d\Sigma^\mu | < \infty$, where $d\Sigma^\mu$ is the directed volume form at future null infinity (https://dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/40046519).
Then, I tried to generalize this for a two form current: 
$| \int_{\mathcal{I}^+} J^{\mu\nu} dS_{\mu\nu} | < \infty$ . The integration element comes from the indices. I think that $dS_{\mu\nu}$ it is the directed surface element on the two-sphere. It is of the form $dS = \gamma^{AB} d\theta_A d\theta_B$, but this doesn't have the right indices. So what is $dS_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: @Robin, the definition of $dS_{\mu\nu}$ is as follows. Recall a $k$-form can be integrated over a $k$-dimensional submanifold. Let $\omega$ be a $(d-2)$-form on a $d$-dimensional Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$. We can integrate it over a codimension two $\Sigma_{d-2}$. On the other hand, the Hodge dual $\star \omega$ is a two-form. We define $dS_{\mu\nu}$ so that $$\int_{\Sigma_{d-2}} \omega = \int_{\Sigma_{d-2}} dS_{\mu\nu}(\star \omega)^{\mu\nu}.$$ Notice that integrating $\omega$ over $\Sigma_{d-2}$ does not require a metric, but writing it as in the RHS needs, because of the Hodge dual.

Comment: Notice in particular the nature of $dS_{\mu\nu}$: it is a matrix of $(d-2)$ forms so that the combination $(\star \omega)^{\mu\nu} dS_{\mu\nu}$ is still a $(d-2)$-form that can be integrated over $\Sigma_{d-2}$.